# Solr schema mapping tool from Database schema

Tags: database, solr, lucene, schema

Is there a tool or library to create a Solr's `schema.xml` from a database schema? We're trying to avoid defining and maintaining hundreds or thousands of fields, and make the process of indexing tables a bit more fluent.

We're looking for something like:

```
table
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

to,

```
<field name="id" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="type" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Alternatively, if nothing of the sort exists, what's a good strategy to map huge tables to Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with database to Solr mapping is that there are too many different databases and lack of standards on DB types (just look at frameworks like Hibernate which attempt to handle every corner case).

On top of that you have all sorts of Solr-specific complexities (analyzers, filters, sorting, etc.) which makes it quite hard to make a generic mapping tool.

Anyway, I believe that few major types should cover most of the cases:

- LongField (signed 64 bit long)
- IntField (signed 32 bit int)
- StrField (single string)
- TextField (text)
- DoubleField (64-bit IEEE floating point)
- BoolField (boolean)

For a complete list of Solr types, refer to [the manual](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr).

Comment: On that regard, is there any support for `DECIMAL` type?

Comment: I don't think there exists something of that sort. Could you convert this to double?

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment; but I wanted to be sure there wasn't a better fit.